# How to improve the arichtecture of a very very basic PHP website?

Tags: php, templating

I have got the job to improve a very basic PHP website. It has no protection against XSS etc, but it is only used internally.

So basically the builder of the website put the html for the main menu on all pages.
This is obviously not following the dry principle. It are roughly 120 pages, all with the menu in them. All working pretty much the same, he checks if the user is logged in and can connect to the database. Then he selects some data from the database, then finally displays it for mostly CRUD operations.

So I have to change all 120 pages, but I don't want to do it just to find out, that there is e cool templating library I missed.
I am coming from a JSF / Java EE background. The JSF templating mechanism is quite strong, i couldn't find an equivalent for PHP.

So with what tools / libraries would you attack this very basic web site?

Comment: i discovered [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) not too long ago.

Comment: @13ruce1337 this looks just what I was looking for, I'll have a closer look at it.

Comment: I just stumbled over [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). The alternative to twig. Just to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of PHP frameworks you could throw at it, but if the main problem is repetition, I think you could get around that with minimal fuss by putting all the common functionality in a file (preferably outside the document root) and [`require`](https://www.php.net/require)ing that from the other pages. Like this, say:

```
<?php  // functions.php
function check_authorization() {
    // ...
}
// lack of close PHP tag is intentional;
// prevents accidental whitespace creeping into page
```

```
<?php  // some other page
require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/functions.php");
// ...
check_authorization();
```